# Rails Search Query for LIKE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am trying to do a Search Query with the LIKE

I have the following Form

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :method => 'get',  :id => 'header-search', :class => 'navbar-form navbar-left', :role => 'search' do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] ,:class => "form-control header-search-input", :placeholder => "Looking for..." %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
@query = params[:query]
    # @venues = Venue.where({ :name => "#@query" })
    @venues = Venue.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE #{@query}"])

    render plain: @venues.to_yaml
```

**Error**

```
Couldn't find all Venues with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name LIKE ooty"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Comment: that's really, really old syntax. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @sevenseacat :( on the web. which is the right way to do it?

Comment: Man...i think i know what is the problem....is that a index,show,edit method? Because this error is about when you are showing an array in a view with an specific id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way I do it. Using `?` lets Rails take care of sql injection stuff.

```
@venues = Venue.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{@query}%")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
 @venues = Venue.where("name like ?", "%#{@query}%")
```

2 things, to avoid sql injection use `?` and `% term %` for searching in query

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be `name LIKE '%ooty%'`, doing a `LIKE` without `%` is the same as `=`.

Comment: while true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sevenseacat If OP use the proper syntax for LIKE, he will most likely get results and no error would be raised, solving the issue "(found 0 results, but was looking for 2)"

Answer (score 2):

For old rails is:

```
    @venues= Venue.find(:all,:conditions=>['name LIKE ?',"%#{@query}%"])
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and safe way to avoid sql injection...
 When you need to find records based on a condition that involves the use of LIKE '%value%' (it's going to be very slow since MySQL won't use an index for this query), try something like the following:

```
    @query = params[:query]
    @venues = Venue.find(:all, :conditions=> ["name like ?",  '%'+@query +'%'])
```